# Why doesn't SO show all comments when there are many?

Tags: support, comments

Is it a problem of performance on the site or that too many make it look way ugly?

Answer (score 2):

Its to avoid cluttering the interface with off and side topic comments.

Comment: So it's not for performance?

Comment: No and yes. Most people that arrives to a question is looking for a solution, not for a discussion, so they wont be needing the comments (usually). By showing a small amount of comments the noise is kept down. By showing everyone the same (cached) page, the performance is improved. But if everyone just expands the comments, that is a biggest load on the server. Of course, if you send smaller pages, the page renders faster. I believe the original intent was to reduce noise, with the added benefit of all that added speed.

Comment: Also, the system favors the highest voted comments, so it will still show useful (or really funny) ones if there are dozens of comments on a post

Comment: Exactly, just as John's comment will be shown even if there are a lot of comments, unless there are lot of higher voted comments :)

Comment: Comments aren't hidden on Meta. The hiding of comments are only valid on the official [S]OFU sites. Meta is about discussion so comments are  hidden only once they have become to many, around 12+

Comment: @Diago: look at longer threads. MSO definitely hides comments beyond a few dozens posts. I've seen it last on the censor thread IIRC

Comment: @voyager: indeed, the comment-hide-threshold is higher here on MSO than on the other sites of the trilogy, but it's definitely here!

Comment: Guys,I've found it's because there is limit on GROUP_CONCAT that SO doesn't show all!

Comment: @Shore - This isn't the case, we don't show all for comments UI - not performance reasons.  We explicitly limit it to 5 on main sites and 15 on metas before comments start hiding.